# Attribute Error Crazyflie

Tags: python, attributeerror, crazyflie

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'is_connected' "
```

When I run the code below:

```
import logging
```

`# Only output errors from the logging framework
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)`

link_uri = 'radio://0/80/250K'
class ParamExample:
    """
    Simple logging example class that logs the Stabilizer from a supplied
    link uri and disconnects after 5s.`
    """

```
def __init__(self, link_uri):
    """ Initialize and run the example with the specified link_uri """

    self._cf = Crazyflie(rw_cache='./cache')

    # Connect some callbacks from the Crazyflie API
    self._cf.connected.add_callback(self._connected)
    self._cf.disconnected.add_callback(self._disconnected)
    self._cf.connection_failed.add_callback(self._connection_failed)
    self._cf.connection_lost.add_callback(self._connection_lost)

    print('Connecting to %s' % link_uri)

    # Try to connect to the Crazyflie
    self._cf.open_link(link_uri)

    # Variable used to keep main loop occupied until disconnect
    self.is_connected = True

    self._param_check_list = []
    self._param_groups = []

    random.seed()

def _connected(self, link_uri):
    """ This callback is called form the Crazyflie API when a Crazyflie
    has been connected and the TOCs have been downloaded."""
    print('Connected to %s' % link_uri)

    # Print the param TOC
    p_toc = self._cf.param.toc.toc
    for group in sorted(p_toc.keys()):
        print('{}'.format(group))
        for param in sorted(p_toc[group].keys()):
            print('\t{}'.format(param))
            self._param_check_list.append('{0}.{1}'.format(group, param))
        self._param_groups.append('{}'.format(group))
        # For every group, register the callback
        self._cf.param.add_update_callback(group=group, name=None,
                                           cb=self._param_callback)

    # You can also register a callback for a specific group.name combo
    self._cf.param.add_update_callback(group='cpu', name='flash',
                                       cb=self._cpu_flash_callback)

    print('')

def _cpu_flash_callback(self, name, value):
    """Specific callback for the cpu.flash parameter"""
    print('The connected Crazyflie has {}kb of flash'.format(value))

def _param_callback(self, name, value):
    """Generic callback registered for all the groups"""
    print('{0}: {1}'.format(name, value))

    # Remove each parameter from the list and close the link when
    # all are fetched
    self._param_check_list.remove(name)
    if len(self._param_check_list) == 0:
        print('Have fetched all parameter values.')

        # First remove all the group callbacks
        for g in self._param_groups:
            self._cf.param.remove_update_callback(group=g,
                                                  cb=self._param_callback)

        # Create a new random value [0.00,1.00] for pid_attitude.pitch_kd
        # and set it
        pkd = random.random()
        print('')
        print('Write: pid_attitude.pitch_kd={:.2f}'.format(pkd))
        self._cf.param.add_update_callback(group='pid_attitude',
                                           name='pitch_kd',
                                           cb=self._a_pitch_kd_callback)
        # When setting a value the parameter is automatically read back
        # and the registered callbacks will get the updated value
        self._cf.param.set_value('pid_attitude.pitch_kd',
                                 '{:.2f}'.format(pkd))

def _a_pitch_kd_callback(self, name, value):
    """Callback for pid_attitude.pitch_kd"""
    print('Readback: {0}={1}'.format(name, value))

    # End the example by closing the link (will cause the app to quit)
    self._cf.close_link()

def _connection_failed(self, link_uri, msg):
    """Callback when connection initial connection fails (i.e no Crazyflie
    at the specified address)"""
    print('Connection to %s failed: %s' % (link_uri, msg))
    self.is_connected = False

def _connection_lost(self, link_uri, msg):
    """Callback when disconnected after a connection has been made (i.e
    Crazyflie moves out of range)"""
    print('Connection to %s lost: %s' % (link_uri, msg))

def _disconnected(self, link_uri):
    """Callback when the Crazyflie is disconnected (called in all cases)"""
    print('Disconnected from %s' % link_uri)
    self.is_connected = False
```

`if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Initialize the low-level drivers (don't list the debug drivers)
    cflib.crtp.init_drivers(enable_debug_driver=False)
    # Scan for Crazyflies and use the first one found
    print('Scanning interfaces for Crazyflies...')
    available = cflib.crtp.scan_interfaces()
    print('Crazyflies found:')
    for i in available:
        print(i[0])`

```
if len(available) > 0:
    pe = ParamExample(available[0][0])
    # The Crazyflie lib doesn't contain anything to keep the application
    # alive, so this is where your application should do something. In our
    # case we are just waiting until we are disconnected.
    with MotionCommander(available,default_height=0.3) as mc:
        while pe.is_connected:
            print('this works')
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print('No Crazyflies found, cannot run example')
```

Comment: Why have you mixed inline code (marked with backticks) and code blocks (indented by four spaces). Is this all meant to be one big file?

Comment: @chris yes it is meant to be one big file

Comment: @AlexQuinto, please edit your question then, and remove the unrequired "`".  I do not want to do it and mess up indentation, since Python is so fussy about it.

Comment: The `{}` button / Ctrl+K keyboard shortcut might be helpful in reformatting your code.